# Text as plot axes values

Tags: plotting

I have some chemical data that I am plotting using `ListLogPlot`.

```
data={{2776.37,2016.64,1483.51,1027.35,500.878,94.1385,310.402,282.548,
       257.886,224.359,218.688,209.312,215.776,198.78}, 
      {40.5063,24.633,12.069,8.3151,6.35135,15.0977,8.74372,15.5125,9.34959,
       9.70696,11.125,12.1457,10.8075,9.7561},
      {113.08,124.633,75.9698,59.5186,55.9459,7.81528,57.4372,69.5291,80.4878,
       88.2784,105.563,127.935,148.571,148.78}};

ListLogPlot[data, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

I want to replace the x-axis tick values with the associated elements.

e.g. replace 1,2,3,...,14 with

```
xaxis= {"La","Ce","Pr","Nd","Sm","Eu","Gd","Tb","Dy","Ho","Er","Tm","Yb","Lu"};
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this? Is there another plot function that I should be using?

Comment: What's the deal with Europium?

Comment: @wxffles  Indeed, europium is [anomalous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europium_anomaly)  :)

Comment: Nice plot, looks like an OIB REE pattern, I suppose you are working in geology/mineralogy?

Comment: @MockupDungeon Actually they are 1.7 - 1.6 Ga granitoids from the Mount Isa inlier, Australia. The samples with the strong negative Eu anomalies are incompatible element enriched granites and the other sample is a pegmatite that may have formed as a partial melt from one of these granites.

Comment: OK, thanks for the details. Pegmatites, yeah, I worked on them as well, from Ikaria, Greece. Li,Be,B-contents.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I personally would also try to style this to see everything better - something like this:

```
ListLogPlot[data, Joined -> True, 
  Ticks -> {Transpose[{Range[14], xaxis}], Automatic}, 
  PlotStyle -> Thick, GridLines -> {Range[14], Automatic}, 
  GridLinesStyle -> Opacity[.5], Mesh -> All, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[.015], Opacity[.5]]] // Magnify
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! Yes, the `GridLines` make it easier to read. Good to know about `Magnify` as well.

Comment: @geordie One might use `MapIndexed` to avoid the hard-coded `14`: `Ticks -> {MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #} &, xaxis], Automatic}`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thanks for the suggestion. I ended up using `Ticks -> {Transpose[{Range@Length@xaxis, xaxis}], Automatic}`. This seems to do pretty much the same thing. Although it is not quite as elegant, it is almost twice as fast according to `AbsoluteTiming`.

Comment: @geordie I use that form a lot myself; it is particularly superior on packed arrays.  However, in this case the speed shouldn't matter; you're not going to have a million tick labels.