# Using ListPlot and lists of Associations

Tags: plotting, associations

I have a list of associations :

```
testdata = {<|"label" -> "v1", "value1" -> -2, "value2" -> 6|>,
<|"label" -> "v2", "value1" -> 4, "value2" -> -4|>,
<|"label" -> "v3", "value1" -> 6, "value2" -> -5|>};
```

The first element of each association is the X axis label, each following key indicates the set of data it belongs to.

Using Vitali's answer [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31679/text-as-plot-axes-values) I have managed to get ListPlot to use each first element as X axis labels, but the code isn't the cleanest due to repeated usage of "testdata"

```
ListPlot[{testdata[[All, 2]], testdata[[All, 3]]}, Joined -> True, 
Ticks -> {Transpose[{Range@Length@testdata[[All, 1]], 
testdata[[All, 1]]}], Automatic}, 
PlotLegends -> DeleteDuplicates@Keys@testdata[[All, 2 ;; 3]]]
```

Using key names is a tiny bit clearer at the expense of verbosity:

```
ListPlot[{testdata[[All, "value1"]], testdata[[All, "value2"]]}, 
Joined -> True, 
Ticks -> {Transpose[{Range@Length@testdata[[All, "label"]], 
testdata[[All, "label"]]}], Automatic}, 
PlotLegends -> DeleteDuplicates@Keys@testdata[[All, 2 ;; 3]]]
```

I believe there must be a way to substitute in a pure function for this usage but am struggling to find it - any ideas?

Note that Im trying to avoid explicit use of Dataset due to its somewhat quirky behaviour in 10.0.x

**BTW**

Named keys in associations doesn't seem to support the ;; span specification syntax of Part - is this a bug?

```
testdata[[All,2;;3]] (* works *)
testdata[[All,"value1";;"value2"]] (* doesnt work *)
```

Comment: You mean something like `ListPlot[testdata[[All,#]]&/@{ "value1","value2"}, Joined -> True, Ticks -> {Transpose[{Range@Length@#, #}]&@testdata[[All, "label"]], Automatic}, PlotLegends -> DeleteDuplicates @Keys @ testdata[[All, 2 ;; 3]]]`?

Comment: @kguler Fairly close to what I was thinking, but was wondering if you can take the testdata completely outside of the main ListPlot expression completely, but somehow retain separate parts inside?  Im probably trying to push things too far :)

Comment: maybe `ListPlot[{#["value1"]&/@#,#["value2"]&/@#}, Joined -> True, Ticks -> {Transpose[{Range@Length@#, #}]&[#["label"]&/@#], Automatic}, PlotLegends -> DeleteDuplicates @Keys[#][[All,2;;]]]&@testdata`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can separate the data element selection from the `ListPlot` generation as follows:

```
testdata[[All, {"label", "value1", "value2"}]] //
ListPlot[
  Transpose @ Values @ #[[All, 2;;]]
, Joined -> True
, Ticks -> {MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #}&, #[[All, 1]]], Automatic}
, PlotLegends -> DeleteDuplicates @ Keys @ #[[All, 2;;]]
]&
```

[image: plot screenshot]

Note the use of a list of keys in `testdata[[All, {"label", "value1", "value2"}]]`.  It is not legal to use key names in spans since, in general, keys are not guaranteed to be in the same order within a list of associations.

The pure function is set up to assume that the first data element is the label and that the remaining data elements are to be plotted.  This allows us to use the expression for other association lists where the keys are different, and appear in jumbled order:

```
testdata2 =
  { <|"x1" -> -10, "x2" -> 30, "title" -> "v1"|>
  , <|"x1" -> 20, "title" -> "v2", "x2" -> 22|>
  , <|"x2" -> 20, "x1" -> 30, "title" -> "v3"|>
  };

testdata2[[All, {"title", "x1", "x2"}]] //
ListPlot[
  Transpose @ Values @ #[[All, 2;;]]
, Joined -> True
, Ticks -> {MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #}&, #[[All, 1]]], Automatic}
, PlotLegends -> DeleteDuplicates @ Keys @ #[[All, 2;;]]
]&
```

[image: plot screenshot]

It is inconvenient to copy-and-paste that long pure function expression each time, so we might consider packaging it up for reuse:

```
myListPlot[data_] :=
  ListPlot[
    Transpose @ Values @ data[[All, 2;;]]
  , Joined -> True
  , Ticks -> {MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], #}&, data[[All, 1]]], Automatic}
  , PlotLegends -> DeleteDuplicates @ Keys @ data[[All, 2;;]]
  ]

testdata[[All, {"label", "value1", "value2"}]] // myListPlot
```

[image: plot screenshot]

```
testdata2[[All, {"title", "x1", "x2"}]] // myListPlot
```

[image: plot screenshot]

Alternatively, we could have the caller explicitly specify the label and data key names:

```
myListPlot2[data_, labelKey_, {dataKeys__}] :=
  data[[All, {labelKey, dataKeys}]] // myListPlot

myListPlot2[testdata2, "title", {"x1", "x2"}]
```

[image: plot screenshot]

Comment: Lovely - exactly what I had in mind.  Still digesting kgulers answer below before marking as answered.

Comment: Lovely answer: addresses all my issues (including the span question) and also contains a logical extrapolation of where I wanted to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

```
ClearAll[listplotF];
listplotF[opts_:{Joined->True}]:= Module[{t, d = Join @@ Through @ 
            {Composition[Transpose, Values], Composition[DeleteDuplicates, Rest/@#&, Keys]}@#}, 
   ListPlot[{#2,#3}, Ticks->(t={Thread[{Range@Length@#,#}],Automatic}),
            FrameTicks->t,
            PlotLegends -> #4, Sequence@@opts]&@@d]&;

listplotF[]@testdata
```

[image]

```
listplotF[{Joined->True,PlotTheme->"Marketing"}]@testdata
```

[image]

Comment: Several new functions to me in that - thanks.