# Plotting a list of associations on same plot and creating legends for each one

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, associations

I have a list of associations that look like this and it goes on for more ts:

```
 testdata = {
  <|"ts" -> "20230727_142041", 
    "Y" -> {121.076, 121.085, 121.094, 121.103, 121.112, 121.121, 121.13, 121.139, 121.148, 121.157, 121.167, 121.176, 121.185, 121.194, 121.203, 121.212, 121.221, 121.23, 121.239, 121.248, 121.257, 121.266, 121.275, 121.284, 121.293, 121.302, 121.311, 121.32, 121.329, 121.338, 121.347, 121.356, 121.365, 121.374, 121.383, 121.392, 121.401, 121.41, 121.419, 121.428, 121.437, 121.446, 121.455, 121.464, 121.473, 121.482, 121.491, 121.499, 121.508, 121.517, 121.526, 121.535, 121.544, 121.553, 121.562}, 
    "X" -> {121.076, 121.085, 121.094, 121.103, 121.112, 121.121, 121.13, 121.139, 121.148, 121.157, 121.167, 121.176, 121.185, 121.194, 121.203, 121.212, 121.221, 121.23, 121.239, 121.248, 121.257, 121.266, 121.275, 121.284, 121.293, 121.302, 121.311, 121.32, 121.329, 121.338, 121.347, 121.356, 121.365, 121.374, 121.383, 121.392, 121.401, 121.41, 121.419, 121.428, 121.437, 121.446, 121.455, 121.464, 121.473, 121.482, 121.491, 121.499, 121.508, 121.517, 121.526, 121.535, 121.544, 121.553, 121.562}|>,.....}
```

After I merged them:

`testdata = JoinAcross[Y, X, "ts"]`

Y and X should be sorted by ts from being previously processed, but I wanted to keep track of data and when it was taken and add legends by ts.

I would like to plot Y and X, and I have tried following this [approach](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69998/using-listplot-and-lists-of-associations?rq=1):

```
testdata[[All, {"Y", "X"}]] // ListLogPlot[Transpose@Values@#[[All, 2 ;;]], Joined -> True, PlotLegends -> Automatic] &
```

I have also tried:

```
test2= Values[testdata[[All, {"Y", "X"}]]] // Transpose
ListLinePlot[test2,PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: You can only join lists. Should  `Join["20230727_142041", "20230727_142041"]` mean `{"20230727_142041", "20230727_142041"}`  ?

Comment: @DanielHuber Thank you for pointing this out. Yes, as in `X` from `ts` and the same for `Y`.

Comment: You did not define X and Y. "X" and "y" are keys inside an association.

Comment: @DanielHuber I have just edited the line for merging. Is it correctly defined now?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `ListLogPlot[<|#ts -> Transpose@{#X, #Y} & /@ testdata|>,  Joined -> True]`?

Comment: @LukasLang Thank you so much! That's exactly what I was looking for. May I ask how WL understood to make the association into legends? I am new to this and will probably work with similar data structures. Also, what was wrong in trying to extract values first then plot them - could it be done?

Comment: @atomic-muclei When you provide the data as `<|"key1"->data1,...|>` to any of the various plotting functions, they will use the keys as legend entries (note that the keys have to be strings for this to work). You can also be more explicit and pass `{Legended[data1,label1],...}` as the first argument (here, any type of label works). As for why your attempts didn't plot anything: You'd need to map `Transpose` over the list of datasets, i.e. `ListLogPlot[Transpose/@Values@#...]` or `test2=Values[...]//Map@Transpose`

Comment: @LukasLang Thank you again for your help.

Comment: @LukasLang Is this plotting each association separately and then stacking them together? It shows 15 legends but on the plot it looks like it's plotting many more than that?

Comment: @atomic-muclei it should plot one line for each legend entry. If you're seeing something different, it's easiest to diagnose what's going on if you can add a more complete example together with a screenshot of what you're seeing to the question.